# C++ rules for covariant virtual function

Tags: c++, c++11, virtual-functions

I was reading [Covariant virtual function](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS2LWA_12.1.0/com.ibm.xlcpp121.bg.doc/language_ref/cplr139.html). It says that

Suppose that B::f overrides the virtual function A::f. The return types of A::f and B::f may differ if all the following conditions are met:

> 1) The const or volatile qualification of the pointer or reference
>   returned by B::f has the same or less const or volatile qualification
>   of the pointer or reference returned by A::f.
>
> 2) A::f returns an lvalue reference if and only if B::f returns an
>   lvalue reference.
>
> 3) The function B::f returns a pointer or a reference to a class of
>   type T, and A::f returns a pointer or a reference to an unambiguous
>   direct or indirect base class of T.
>
> 4) The return type of B::f must be complete at the point of declaration of B::f,  or it can be of type B

Will someone explain the above 2 rules by giving suitable example? What exactly these 2 rules mean?Is the second rule is applicable from C++11?
Is the following example satisfies 1st rule I've said here?

```
#include <iostream>
class Base {
    public:
        virtual const Base& fun() const
        {
            std::cout<<"fun() in Base\n";
            return *this;
        }
        virtual ~Base()
        { }
    private:
        int a=3;
};
class Derived : public Base
{
        const Derived& fun() const
        {
            std::cout<<"fun() in Derived\n";
            return *this;
        }
};
int main(){
    Base* p=new Derived();
    p->fun();
    delete p;
    return 0;
}
```

Please correct me If I am wrong somewhere.I am confused in first 2 rules.

Thanks

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The second point should be *"both [return types] are pointers to classes, both are lvalue references to classes, or both are rvalue references to
classes"*, as in [class.virtual]p7.1 of the C++ Standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first rule means that you can't make an overridden function return a `B` which has `const` or `volatile` if the `A` version does not:

```
struct A
{
    virtual A* foo() { return new A{}; }    
};

struct B : A
{
    B* foo() override {return new B{}; }          //valid
    const B* foo() override {return new B{}; }    //invalid
    volatile B* foo() override {return new B{}; } //invalid
};
```

This makes sense if the think about the call site:

```
A* my_b = new B{};
A* new_b = my_b->foo(); //discards the const qualifier if B::foo() returns const B*
```

The second rule means that you can't have disparate reference or pointer types as covariant return types. Using the same example as above:

```
struct A
{
    virtual A* foo() { return new A{}; }    
};

struct B : A
{
    B* foo() override {return new B{}; }   //valid
    B& foo() override {return new B{}; }   //invalid
    B&& foo() override {return new B{}; }  //invalid
};
```

Again, think about the call site:

```
A* my_b = new B{};
A* new_b = my_b->foo(); //if B::foo() returns a reference, this line is syntactically ill-formed
```

Your example satisfies both rules because both return types have the same cv-qualification and are both lvalue references.

Comment: I think there is typo. "you can't make an overloaded function" should be replaced by you can't make an overridden function"

Comment: It will be better if you could also add deallocation statements (use of delete operators) to release memory.

Comment: Absolutely right about the typo. Deallocation is pretty removed from the concepts of covariant return types, so I didn't include them. In real code you would have a virtual destructor and use smart pointers to manage the memory.